# Networkx unhashable type: 'dict'

Tags: python, function, dictionary, networkx

I get an error unhashable type: 'dict' when trying to assign neighbors

```
graphs = networkx.erdos_renyi_graph(10, 0.5)
pos = random.choice(graphs.nodes())
neighbors = graphs.neighbors(pos)

TypeError       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-97-f39c9dfc00ff> in <module>()
  1 graphs = networkx.erdos_renyi_graph(10, 0.5)
  2 pos = random.choice(graphs.nodes())
  ----->3 neighbors = graphs.neighbors(pos)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/networkx/classes/graph.py 
in neighbors(self, n)
1251         
1252         try:
-> 1253             return iter(self._adj[n])
1254         except KeyError as e:
1255             raise NetworkXError(f"The node {n} is not in the 
graph.") from e
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see what you have in variables.

Comment: when I run it then `pos` is empty dictionary. What did you expect to get in `pos`? Maybe you should use `if/else` to check `pos` and skip `graphs.neighbors(pos)` - `if pos: neighbors = graphs.neighbors(pos)  else:  neighbors = []`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with all the intricacies of the networkx `NodeDataView` object (your `graphs.nodes()`), but the notes and examples in [the documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.nodes.html) suggest simply converting to a `list` to access the nodes for sequence-type operations.

The following works for me as expected without any errors.

```
import networkx
import random

graphs = networkx.erdos_renyi_graph(10, 0.5)
pos = random.choice(list(graphs.nodes))
neighbors = graphs.neighbors(pos)
```

As an aside, since the variable name `pos` has another typical meaning as [kwarg which specifies node coordinates for plotting in networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html#drawing), it might be best to use another variable name to prevent confusion.